# Solving linear equations involving many variables

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I know that to solve a linear equation involving $n$ variables for example, we need $n-1$ other independent equations to form a system and then solve that system. Is there a formal proof for this?

Comment: It depends on the type of equation.  Are they all linear?  Occurring over a field?

Comment: I'm talking about linear equations

Comment: The solution can only be unique , if we have at least as many equations than variables. This can be shown by looking at the poosible ranks of the coefficient matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof: if we didn't have n equations for n unknowns, then the matrix representing the system would either be rectangular (meaning no unique solution) or have zero rows (also no unique solutions). Therefore there must be n equations for n unknowns in order for a unique solution to exist.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a system of linear equations, then you can use Gauss-Jordan elimination to get the solutions. You can also take the determinant of the coefficient matrix first to check whether or not you'll have a single solution, infinitely many solutions, or zero solutions.